# Rename list objects in Python

Tags: python

I have a python code that prints objects that I want to rename to use later

```
import urllib.request as url

pagina = "https://s3-ifc-coordinador-preprod.s3.amazonaws.com/"
pw = url.urlopen(pagina)
datos = pw.readlines()
print(datos)
for i in datos:
    datos2 = i.decode("utf-8").split("BAEN/")
    for j in datos2:
        if j.count(".xlsx") > 0:
            referencia = j.split("<")
            #new_referencia = referencia.replace('Ago2019', 'May2020')
            #print(new_referencia[0])
            print(referencia[0])
```

Result:

```
VE02_FIFC_LUZOSORNO_BAENAgo2019.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_NORVIND_BAENAgo2019.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_POZO_ALMONTE_SOLAR_1_BAENAgo2019.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_SAESA_BAENAgo2019.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_SAFIRA_ENERGIA_CHILE_BAENAgo2019.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_SAN_JUAN_LAP_BAENAgo2019.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_SGA_BAENAgo2019.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_TACORA_ENERGY_BAENAgo2019.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_TRANSELEC_BAENAgo2019.xlsx
VE03_FIFC_AES_GENER_BAENAgo2019.xlsx
VE03_FIFC_CALAMA_SOLAR_1_BAENAgo2019.xlsx
VE03_FIFC_ENGIE_BAENAgo2019.xlsx
```

I need to change 'Ago2019' to 'May2020'

Clearly using replace(), it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?

Result I require

```
VE02_FIFC_LUZOSORNO_BAENMay2020.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_NORVIND_BAENMay2020.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_POZO_ALMONTE_SOLAR_1_BAENMay2020.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_SAESA_BAENMay2020.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_SAFIRA_ENERGIA_CHILE_BAENMay2020.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_SAN_JUAN_LAP_BAENMay2020.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_SGA_BAENMay2020.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_TACORA_ENERGY_BAENMay2020.xlsx
VE02_FIFC_TRANSELEC_BAENMay2020.xlsx
VE03_FIFC_AES_GENER_BAENMay2020.xlsx
VE03_FIFC_CALAMA_SOLAR_1_BAENMay2020.xlsx
VE03_FIFC_ENGIE_BAENMay2020.xlsx
```

Comment: Why exactly "Clearly using replace() doesn't work"?

Comment: The way I did it throws me an error: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: @LuisFernandoSilva you must use `replace` on a string - You are using it on a list -- perhaps list comprehension might work -- `new_referencia = [i.replace('Ago2019', 'May2020') for i in referencia]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) on a string:

```py
new_referencia = [i.replace('Ago2019', 'May2020') for i in referencia]
```

NOTE: `split()` creates a `list`

Answer (score 1):

The replace is probably fine, but you haven't replaced it in the array, instead you've assigned it to a new variable that you never use.

Try something like this:

```
        referencia = j.split("<")
        new_referencia = referencia[0].replace('Ago2019', 'May2020')
        print(new_referencia)
```